# How to deploy c++ Console application on VM or Kubernetes?

Tags: c++, web-applications, console

I want to deploy a c++ console application for a webapp on VM or Kubernetes. Could you help on the steps ?

Comment: So, you have an app already and want to know how to deploy it?

Comment: Yes I want my webapp to run that console app all the time